# difference between regular loop and splice in angular filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-filter

Below is a fragment of code in one of my angular filters which i am using with bootstrap pagination.

```
//first statement
let ret = [];

for (let i = from; i < limit + from; i++) {
  if (typeof items[i] !== typeof undefined) {
    ret.push(items[i]);
  }
}

//second statement
ret = items.splice(from, limit);
```

Using the first statement works as expected without any error while the second one results in an infinite digest loop.
What's the difference?

Edit : Full code below (as requested by T.J. Crowder)

```
     filter('limitMe',function () {
        return function (items,limit, from) {
            if(
                typeof items == typeof undefined ||
                typeof limit == typeof undefined ||
                typeof from == typeof undefined
            ){
                return items;
            }
            let len = items.length;
            if(len == 0){
                return items;
            }
            if(limit > len){
                limit = len;
                from = 0;
            }else if(len < from + limit){
                limit = len - from;
            }
            let ret = [];
            for(let i = from; i < limit + from; i++){
                if(typeof items[i] !== typeof undefined){
                    ret.push(items[i])
                }
            }
            /*return items.filter(function (row) {
                return typeof row !== typeof undefined;
            }).splice(from, limit);*/
            return ret;
        }
    })
```

Comment: maybe this could works items.filter((item)=>{return item !== typeof undefined}).splice(from, limit);

Comment: thanks @InferOn i will try that right now

Comment: Apologies for my first answer, I read `slice` where the code clearly uses `splice`.

Comment: @InferOn adding the filter worked but why? How come a simple splice results in infinite digest loop and a filter before that fixes it?

Comment: how do you use your filter? Could you add a piece of markup?

Comment: here it is:
<div ng-repeat="value in vm.generalProperties | limitMe : vm.itemsPerPageGeneral : vm.itemsPerPageGeneral * (vm.currentPageGeneral - 1) track by $index" class="row"><!--- rest inside here --></div>
 vm.itemsPerPageGeneral = 5 and vm.currentPageGeneral =1

Answer (score 0):

The two code samples do completely different things:

- The first *copies* non-`undefined`, non-missing entries in the range `from` to `limit + from` into `ret`, also leaving them in `items`.
- The second *removes* entries from `items` and puts them in `ret` (even if those entries are `undefined` or missing).

So after the first, `items` still has the entries in it. After the second, it doesn't.

Separately, the second will take `undefined` entries from `items` if they're in range, whereas the second will skip them.

If you post an [MCVE](/help/mcve), we can probably help you understand why those make for an infinite digest loop, but they're pretty major differences (particularly the first), so...